# What is the difference between required and ng-required?

Tags: angularjs, required

What is the difference between `required` and `ng-required` (form validation)?

Answer (score 425, accepted):

AngularJS form elements look for the `required` attribute to perform validation functions. `ng-required` allows you to set the `required` attribute depending on a boolean test (for instance, only require field B - *say, a student number* - if the field A has a certain value - *if you selected "student" as a choice*)

As an example, `<input required>` and `<input ng-required="true">` are essentially the same thing

If you are wondering **why** this is this way, (and not just make `<input required="true">` or `<input required="false">`), it is due to the limitations of HTML - the `required` attribute has no associated value - its mere presence means (as per HTML standards) that the element is required - so angular needs a way to set/unset required value (`required="false"` would be invalid HTML)

Comment: How can I remove ng-required respectively? Because I tried some jquery methods with no success

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.. In practice, you never use ng-required="true", but rather ng-required="scopedVariable" or ng-required="scopeTruthTest()", and the value of the variable/function determines if the element is required. Never use jquery to mess with these things in an angular app, or you'll have unpredictable results!

Comment: Its worth mentioning that ng-required displays a default tooltip style error message saying 'this field is required', which is not always desired. I'm looking for a way to turn it off

Comment: It doesn't, really. Not sure, but I think what you're referring to is html5 validation, which is preformed automatically by most modern browsers. If you want to take control over this (disabling what the browser does) you can add the attribute novalidate: `<form method="post" action="/foo" novalidate>`. Again, this is a html5 attribute, not related to angularJS.

Comment: I would have expected that when `ng-required` points to a scope/controller variable, Angular monitors it for changes and sets the required attribute accordingly. While in the case of the simple HTML `required` attribute you don't have that kind of flexibility. No? And while we're on the same topic, what about `ng-attr-required`? Is it exactly the same as `ng-required`?

Answer (score 78):

I would like to make a addon for [tiago's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16648851/439427):

Suppose you're hiding element using `ng-show` and adding a `required` attribute on the same:

```
<div ng-show="false">
    <input required name="something" ng-model="name"/>
</div>
```

will throw an error something like :

> An invalid form control with name='' is not focusable

This is because you just cannot impose `required` validation on `hidden` elements. Using `ng-required` makes it easier to **conditionally apply** required validation which is just awesome!!

Comment: Definitely a good tip, and you can also use `ng-if` instead of `ng-show`/`ng-hide` to sidestep that potential issue.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. If you have hidden elements (ng-show="false"), there is a difference between ng-required="true" and just 'required' as described in this answer, and we got into hot water because of this difference.

Answer (score 18):

The **HTML attribute** `required="required"` is a statement telling the browser that this field is required in order for the form to be valid. (`required="required"` is the XHTML form, just using `required` is equivalent)

The **Angular attribute** `ng-required="yourCondition"` means 'isRequired(yourCondition)' and sets the HTML attribute **dynamically** for you depending on your condition.

Also note that **the HTML version is confusing**, it is **not** possible to write something conditional like `required="true"` or `required="false"`, only the presence of the attribute matters (present means true) ! This is where Angular helps you out with `ng-required`.

Comment: Yes sadly the browser does not allow to put true/false, probably considered too technical...