# Using ng-required vs required

Tags: angularjs

I have the following multi select box:

```
<select 
    multiple="multiple" 
    data-ng-model="rightSelected" 
    data-ng-options="slide as slide.SlideBarcode for slide in form.Slides" 
    data-ng-required="form.Slides.length > 0" 
/>
```

In my controller I do this at initialization:

```
$scope.form.Slides = [];
```

I want this element of the form to be valid if there are slides in the Slide array.  These are added dynamically- it's kind of a slide bucket users can add slides to.

But I'm not getting how the ngRequired stuff works... if I change it to `data-ng-required="true"` then my form looks okay, but of course it doesn't do what I want.  If I use the `form.Slides.length > 0` which is checking for what I really want, not only does this not work, but it messes with my form structure, one of my elements vanishes seemingly at random.

What is the proper way to use this?  The docs are pretty sparse on this one.

Comment: you can sidestep the issue by disabling or hiding the submit button until the form is in a valid state, in other words prevent users from submitting invalid data.  `<button type='submit' ng-show='formIsValid()'>Submit</button>`  then, add the method `formIsValid()` on your $scope which checks the state of the ng-model

Comment: Hmm, Im not sure this will work- there are lots of other form elements that I need to validate.  I already use `data-ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid"` on the submit button.  Kinda not cool to have to manage all this in a `formIsValid()` method.  Or maybe I can use the `myForm.$invalid` in that method?  I'll check into it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Check out this post:

[What is the difference between required and ng-required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16648669/angular-what-is-the-difference-between-required-and-ng-required)

From what I think you're trying to do, I think you're using the ng-required attribute wrong. The ng-required attribute is for when you want to conditionally require an input or not. I'm guessing in your case you always want that input to be required.

As per your comments, if you don't want to manage to any functions, I would put all of these in one function

```
$scope.isFormValid= function(){
    if (form.Slides.length > 0 && myForm.$valid)
        return true;
}
```

and then

```
ng-disabled="isFormValid()"
```

This may not be the most elegant solution but it works. Let me know if that's not what you wanted.