# Angularjs Validation: Require at least one input from a list

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, validation

I'm trying to use Angularjs validation to enable a button when at least one input from a list is filled in. What I'm working on is similar to the following w3schools example:

```
<head>
    <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>Validation Example</h2>

    <form ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="validateCtrl" name="myForm" novalidate>

        <p>Username:<br>
        <input type="text" name="user" ng-model="user" required>
        <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.user.$dirty && myForm.user.$invalid">
        <span ng-show="myForm.user.$error.required">Username is required.</span>
        </span>
        </p>

        <p>Email:<br>
        <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="email" required>
        <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.email.$dirty && myForm.email.$invalid">
        <span ng-show="myForm.email.$error.required">Email is required.</span>
        <span ng-show="myForm.email.$error.email">Invalid email address.</span>
        </span>
        </p>

        <p>
        <input type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.user.$dirty && myForm.user.$invalid || myForm.email.$dirty && myForm.email.$invalid>"
        </p>

    </form>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('validateCtrl', function($scope) {
            $scope.user = 'John Doe';
            $scope.email = 'john.doe@gmail.com';
        });
    </script>

</body>
```

I tried adding a div containing two inputs with a "required" tag as follows but to no avail:

```
<div name="address" ng-model="address" required>
<input name="address1" ng-model="address1">
<input name="address2" ng-model="address2">
```

What would be the best way to do this with angular validation?

Comment: I found a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13466133/how-can-i-conditionally-require-form-inputs-with-angularjs

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The *ng-required* directive can help you for your this like conditional requirement needs.

For example:

```
<div name="addresses">
  <input name="address1" ng-model="address1" ng-required="!address2">
  <input name="address2" ng-model="address2" ng-required="!address1">
</div>
```

Comment: This does not work for all cases, specially when the checkbox checked and unchecked, the module does not change simultaneously

Answer (score 3):

I'd use `ng-required` for that case

```
<input ng-required="mustBeFilled()" ng-model="myModel" />
<input ng-required="mustBeFilled()" ng-model="myOtherModel" />
```

then

```
$scope.mustBeFilled = function () {
  if($scope.myModel.length || $scope.otherModel.length){
    return false
  } else {
    return true
  }
}
```

so as soon as one input is filled the inputs won't be required, using require gives you control over some functionalities like using classes from form to display messages

and for submit button you can add

```
ng-disabled="formName.$invalid"
```

Answer (score 0):

Require them to have entered something into one of the fields as follows:

```
ng-disabled="!user && !email"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below. [Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XrHQbGwMOQLdWKVmhyvU?p=preview)

```
 <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <form name="userForm" novalidate > 
    Name:
    <input type="text" name='userName' ng-model="firstName" required />
  </form>

  <input type = 'button' id="buttonId"  value = 'Submit'  ng-disabled="!userForm.userName.$dirty"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved it including validation. Of course ng-pattern optional if needed. Thank you for this post!

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MainController', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.checkSubmit = function() {
      if ($scope.myform.$valid) {
        //should also be valid if only one number is available
        alert('form is valid...');
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">

  <div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="MainController">
    <form name="myform" ng-submit="checkSubmit()" novalidate>
      <!-- mobile -->
      <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': (myform.$submitted && myform.mobile.$invalid) || (myform.mobile.$invalid && !myform.mobile.$pristine)}">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="mobile">Mobile: *</label>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <input ng-required="!data.home" id="mobile" name="mobile" type="tel" class="form-control" ng-model="data.mobile">
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- home -->
      <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': (myform.$submitted && myform.home.$invalid) || (myform.home.$invalid && !myform.home.$pristine)}">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="home">Home: *</label>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <input ng-required="!data.mobile" id="home" name="home" type="tel" class="form-control" ng-model="data.home">
          <div ng-class="{'has-error': ((myform.$submitted && myform.mobile.$invalid) || (myform.mobile.$invalid && !myform.mobile.$pristine)) || ((myform.$submitted && myform.home.$invalid) || (myform.home.$invalid && !myform.home.$pristine))}">
            <span class="help-block">Please enter at least one phone number.</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Button (Double) -->
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-12 buttons">
          <button id="button" type="submit" name="button" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </form>

    <!-- info -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <br/>Mobile -> {{myform.mobile.$valid}} - {{myform.mobile.$error}}
        <br/>Home -> {{myform.mobile.$valid}} - {{myform.mobile.$error}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```