# How do I Add multiple conditions to either form ng-submit or Textbox ng-enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, forms

In my JSP code, I try to use ng-submit on a form.

The problem is that there are many validations for the textboxes of that form which are implemented using ng-disabled in Submit button.

Now if I click enter key on a textbox then those validations will not be implemented and the form will be submitted.

How can I add the conditions here?

The only option I could think is to move all the conditions of ng-disabled to Javascript function.

```
<form name="customersForm" ng-submit="findCustomers(custName, custCity)">

    <button type=submit **ng-disabled="validateInputs(custName,custCity)"**  
id="listButton" ng-click="findCustomers(custName,custCity)"><span>Find </span></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `novalidate` attribute to your form and add the `required` attribute to your form elements. From there, you can play with the validation of your form with the `ng-` directives. The form wont be submitted until all the fields are properly filled.

Comment: I have 2 input fields and either one of them is only mandatory. How to achieve this?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24227903/form-validation-required-one-of-many-in-a-group)