# Angular: Show one validation message for 2 fields (using ng-messages)

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation

[image]

As you can see from the above screenshot, I have 2 fields (first name, last name).

And I don't want to show 2 similar messages (`This field is required`) under each field. But I want to have only one message (under these 2 fields).

How should I do in this case in order to have that?

Given the fact that I'm using `ng-messages`.

Any reply would help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited:

Maybe you can find answer from here [Form validation - Required one of many in a group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24227903/form-validation-required-one-of-many-in-a-group)

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I appreciate. Looking into your code, I guess at some point, there will be 2 messages showing instead of 1 (when user focus on the first name field)?

Comment: Oh, I miss infor in your question, try solution of @ExpertSystem from link above

Comment: Thanks a lot, very helpful link. Exactly what I need.