# add remove required validation in angular dynamically in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have a form as shown below, I have kept only 1 field here for simplicity. In my form I have many other fields including a country dropdown. If country selected is A,B or C I want to remove the required validation which I do using a `addressRequired` which gets a true/false value on change of country.

I am removing the required using `.removeAttr()` and it does get remove from the html.

But the `ng-disabled="myAbcForm.$invalid"` stills shows invalid.

```
<form name="myAbcForm" ng-submit="submitForm(myAbcForm.$valid)" novalidate class="myAbcForm">
   <div class="element-box fltlt">
        <label>Address </label><sup ng-show="addressRequired">*</sup>
        <input type="text" value="" ng-model="details.Address" required="">
        <span ng-show="!details.Address && addressRequired" class="error-msg field-validation-error">Address is required.</span>
    </div>
    <div id="clearfix">
        <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn fltlt btnBG" ng-disabled="myAbcForm.$invalid" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: For more information check this:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16648669/what-is-the-difference-between-required-and-ng-required][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16648669/what-is-the-difference-between-required-and-ng-required

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ngRequired` instead, like:

```
ng-required="checkCountry()"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/0jz49knd/1/

Comment: what should the `checkCountry()` function return ? a bool ?

Comment: @Yasser, yes, I'm on the fiddle, but yes, just like that.

Comment: Thanks got a solution from your answer.

Answer (score 1):

With a little hint from [coma's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/94144/coma) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26774794/1182982)

Here is what I am using now

```
<input type="text" value="" 
  ng-model="details.Address" 
  ng-required="addressRequired" />
```