# angularjs required and ng-required which one is good without any issues for validate the fields

Tags: angularjs

I have one template

```
<form ng-submit="save()" ng-controller="formController">
  <input type="text" ng-model="textValue1" required /></br>
  <input type="text" ng-model="textValue2" ng-required="true" /></br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

here both are validating fine when i clicked submit button,may i know which scenario these things can use exactly in angularjs.

Answer (score 0):

'AngularJS form elements look for the required attribute to perform validation functions. ng-required allows you to set the required attibute depending on a boolean test (for instance, only require field B - say, a student number - if the field A has a certain value - if you selected "student" as a choice)

As an example, `<input required>` and `<input ng-required="true">` are essentially the same thing

If you are wondering why this is this way, (and not just make `<input required="true">` or `<input required="false">`), it is due to the limitations of HTML - the required attribute has no associated value - it's mere presence means (as per HTML standards) that the element is required - so angular needs a way to set/unset required value (`required="false"` would be invalid HTML)'

Source: [What is the difference between required and ng-required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16648669/what-is-the-difference-between-required-and-ng-required)

Comment: If you're going to wholesale copy an answer, you should have voted to close as duplicate instead.

Comment: Oh ok, didnt knew that! Thanks!

Comment: Just did it :) thanks again, didnt knew about that feature :)

Answer (score 0):

`ng-required="condition"` is similar to `required="{{condition}}"`.
No difference than this.

Comment: Ok Kiran Reddy no difference,then may i know why 2 attributes here required and ng-required.can u tell exact place which is useful without any issues.

Comment: If you want to give required to an input and don't want to change it later as in your code both behave similarly. But if you want to update the required attribute dynamically based on a condition/variable then it is just a difference in the syntax, nothing more than that.