# Angular form validation seems to add class of ng-xx-required whether input is required or not?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, input

When an input is **required**, `ng-invalid-required` is added as a class and `required="required"` is being set as an attribute.

When an input is **not required**, `ng-valid-required` is added as a class and no required attribute is being set as an attribute.

(A good way to add required to an input, is through setting a variable on the scope and using `ng-required` as per Plunkr.)

[Here is Plunkr example with one required input and one non required input](http://plnkr.co/edit/VMIB4UvTB1omrpvxivi6?p=preview)

What I am struggling with is trying to find specific documentation on the `ng-valid-required`. I feel slightly confused as the why there's a class with ng-xx-required, when the input is **not required**.

Thanks in advance for your time. 
ROCK ON!

Comment: could you create plunkr with a problem?

Comment: In your plunkr, using Firefox, I get **ng-valid-required** on the second input box, and ng-invalid-required on the first. This looks correct, what browser are you using?

Comment: @MarkHughes I get the same on Chrome.

Comment: The question is - am I being a massive idiot? `ng-invalid-required` for the required input and `ng-valid-required` for the non required - I can't find documentation on the exact meanings on these. I would have thought `ng-xxx-required` would only be added when the field is required. I can't find any good documentation on this specific required class meaning.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually working this solution:

```
<input type="text" name="userName" ng-model="user.name" ng-required="required">
```

The problem is pearhaps in variable definition see plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/DBcwDeuKJq8Zp1b3daOV?p=preview

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct (whether it works or not) - required="false" is not valid HTML as per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16648851/789529)

Comment: I played with the plunker and yes you are right it is not changing anything actually. ng-required=false is sufficent.

Comment: The question is asking to set ng-required from a scope variable though, so think this doesn't answer the problem.

Comment: and replacing boolean by a variable defined in controller still work also.

Comment: I updated a new version of plunker. I think the problem is scope definition in Mag code snippet.

Comment: @Mag I forked my plunk with the exact input date and added a button on it. i only get a **ng-valid-required** when required=false and **ng-invalid-required** when required=true

Comment: Thanks, you helped me to see I was missing the subtlety difference in my speed reading between ```ng-valid-required``` and ```ng-invalid-required```. Would still love to see specific documentation on these.