# Angular: how to bind to required/ngRequired

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, required

I have this directive which can be required or not. It can be used in two ways (as far as I know)

```
<my-foo required></my-foo>
```

or

```
<my-foo ng-required="data.value > 10"></my-foo>
```

So, because [`require` and `ngRequire` are basically the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16648669/what-is-the-difference-between-required-and-ng-required) you would think that the directive could do this

HTML:

```
<my-foo ng-require="data.isRequired"></my-foo>
```

JS:

```
...
.directive('myFoo', function () {
    return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
       required: '='
    }
    ...
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/pLvmf9qg/24/)

Well, nope, this doesn't work, `scope.require` is `undefined`. You actually have to change the scope definition to

```
scope: {
    required: '=ngRequired'
}
```

So the question is what is the preferred way to handle both situation such that the value gets stored in `scope.required` ? Should I defined both or use attrs from the link function ?

Comment: why would you expect this to work?  As soon as you use ng-require, you are invoking a separate directive, not passing a parameter to YOUR directive.

Comment: What does it mean that you have a "directive which can be required or not"?

Comment: Its a custom form element, which can have the required attribute. For example you can you require.ngRequire on the input element, why not on my custom element ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are basically 2 approaches you can pick:

### 1. Custom form element supporting `ng-model`

If you peek at the `ng-required` directive source code you'll find it only deals with [`ng-model` controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController):

```
restrict: 'A',
require: '?ngModel',
link: function(scope, elm, attr, ctrl) {
  if (!ctrl) return;
  attr.required = true; // force truthy in case we are on non input element

  ctrl.$validators.required = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
    return !attr.required || !ctrl.$isEmpty(viewValue);
  };

  attr.$observe('required', function() {
    ctrl.$validate();
  });
}
```

Thus if you custom directive supports `ng-model` you already have support for `ng-required` i.e.:

```js
angular.module('test', [])
.directive('myInput', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: true,
    template: '<div><button ng-click="changeValue()">Change Value from: {{currentValue}}</button></div>',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
        ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(val){
          if(!val){
            return null;
          }
          return parseFloat(val, 10) * 100;
        });
        ngModelCtrl.$render = function() {
           scope.currentValue = ngModelCtrl.$viewValue || 'No value';
        };
        scope.changeValue = function read(){
          var newValue = Math.random();
          if(newValue > 0.5){
            ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(newValue + "");
          } else {
            ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(null);
          }
          ngModelCtrl.$render();
        };
    }
  };
});
```

### 2. Wrap existing directive and pass `ng-required`:

```js
angular.module('test', [])
  .directive('myFormElement', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
          model: '=',
          required: '='
        },
        template: '<div>Enter number: <input type="number" ng-model="data.number" ng-required="required"></div>'
  };

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="test" ng-init="data={value:'Initial', required: false}">
  <form>
    Is required: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="data.required">
    <my-form-element required="data.required" model="data"></my-form-element>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have it working now, except for the initial state. I've created a better [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pLvmf9qg/38/) In there I log `attrs.required` to the console and as you can see initially its always `true`. Is there some way to fix this ?

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri Try `console.log(attr.ngRequired)`. The `ngRequire` always set's `attrs.required=true` - see above.

Comment: ah, I see `attr.required = true;` :) Thanks again!

Comment: Just one last thing. I noticed that when you have a wrapper, the error is not visible anymore, because the form $error occurs on the inner input element. What would be the correct way to map this to the wrapper element ? One possible solution is to give the inner input the same value for the `name` attribute, which seems to work