# Is there a need to set ng-required and ng-minlength for an input?

Tags: angularjs

I've been doing some tests and it would seem that just setting `required="required"` and `minlength="5"` does exactly that same thing as setting the `ng- versions`.

Has anyone else come across this?

Comment: Check out this post, for ng-required [What is the difference between required and ng-required?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16648669/what-is-the-difference-between-required-and-ng-required)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are sure of whether the field is **required** or the **minimum length of the input**,  `input name=n required minlength=12` is fine. But when there are variables/functions governing those decisions, `minlength=name.minLength`, wouldn't make sense.

Then we need to use `input ng-required="isThisTrue()" ng-minlength="name.minLength"`.

Answer (score 1):

The *required* and *minlength*  attributes are *HTML5* form validation tools. When you want to implement validation, you can use HTML5 attributes or Angular validation directives. The advantage of using the Angular directives is that you can access a lot of features like:

- Custom class depending of the form state:

  - **ng-valid**: the model is valid
  - **ng-invalid**: the model is invalid
  - **ng-pristine**: the control hasn't been interacted with yet
  - **ng-dirty**: the control has been interacted with
  - **ng-touched**: the control has been blurred
  - **ng-untouched**: the control hasn't been blurred

You also have the above properties for each element in the form:

```
<form name="my_form" novalidate>
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" name="user_name" required="" />
    <div ng-show="my_form.user_name.$touched">You have make changes to the field</div>
    <div ng-show="my_form.$submitted || my_form.user_name.$touched">
        <div ng-show="form.uName.$error.required">You don't have a name :(</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, as you can notice in the example above, you can show a custom error message for each validation rule.